# iterate over dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, iteration

Suppose a dataframe as the following:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dept':['dept1','dept2','dept3','dept4','dept5'],
                 'room1':['0','1','1','NA','1'],
                 'room2':['1','0','NA','1','1'],
                 'room3':['0','0','1','NA','1'],
                 'room4':['1','NA','1','1','1'],
                 'count':['4','3','3','2','4']}


        dept  room1  room2 room3  room4 count
0      dept1    0      1     0      1    4
1      dept2    1      0     0      NA   3
2      dept3    1      NA    1      1    3
3      dept4    NA     1    NA      1    2
4      dept5    1      1    1       1    4
```

How to iterate over dataframe to check if the cell that is not NULL in each row if its 0 or 1?

I tried  `iteritem()`  but it did not return the correct answer also when i tried to use if statement to check if the value is 1 or 0 the system crash.

expected result :

highlight the last record because all the room have value **1** so the dept is locked

is this possible .
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check

```
cond = df.filter(like='room').eq(1).all(1)
Out[428]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
#df[cond]
```

Comment: OK THANKS  i have a question what if i want to check the dept3 and consider it as **locked**  let say because the `count = 3` and the values are 1 how to deal with this?

also each room has a different name but for the purpose of the example its called room1 rrom2 .

thank you.

Comment: i tried your answer but it did not work it display the below error:
`No axis named 1 for object type DataFrame`